# End date is not working in add to calender

Tags: android, android-calendar

I want to add event to the calender. The event must show for a particular time period.
for getting start time and end time using the code:

```
  java.sql.Timestamp tsStart = java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf(2014 + "-" + 10
            + "-" + 25 + " " + 10 + ":" + 25 + ":00");
    java.sql.Timestamp tsEnd = java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf(2014 + "-" + 12
            + "-" + 25 + " " + 11 + ":" + 25 + ":00");

    mStartTime = tsStart.getTime();
    mEndTime = tsEnd.getTime();
```

here start time is 25,OCt 2014
 and end time is 25, Dec 2014.

```
               ContentValues event = new ContentValues();
                event.put("calendar_id", 1);
                event.put("eventTimezone", TimeZone.getDefault().getID());
                event.put("title", "test");
                event.put("description","description");
                event.put("dtstart", mStartTime);
                event.put("dtend", mEndTime);
                event.put("rrule", "FREQ=MONTHLY");
                event.put("allDay", 1); 
                event.put("eventStatus", 1);
                event.put("hasAlarm", 1);
               Uri url = getContentResolver().insert(mEventsUri, event);
```

This is code i am used for add to the calender. but event is not updated correctly in calender. ie, event will show beyond the end date. how can i resolve this issue?
Please help me....

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of Calender Instance instead of creating java.sql object.

I tried the following to set future time and make it run until the date specified.

```
Calendar currentDate = Calendar.getInstance();
```

currentDate reads the current device time.

```
final Calendar future = Calendar.getInstance();

// Month 0-January, 11-December
future.set(2014, 9, 25, 23, 59, 59);
```

Create an handler to check for the future date Instance.

```
// runs every second 
final Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    handler.postDelayed(this, 1000); // set time in milliseconds

                    if (future.before(currentDate)) {
                        close_app();
                    }
                }
            }, 1000);
```

`future.before(currentDate)` checks for future time.